# PHP/MySQL reading color,names from tables isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

As you might know from my previous questions, I'm working on this football manager.

Well, I have made two tables: users and teams.
In the users table, there are these fields: id, username, password, team
In the teams table: id, team, teamname, color1, color2, league, money

(if you're wondering why I made team and teamname, it's because team is the shorter version and teamname is expanded)

And I have tried to read the teamname and place it into a button as a value, but it couldn't read.

```
<button value=
    <?php mysql_query("SELECT `teamname` FROM `teams` WHERE `team` = '". mysql_query("SELECT `team` FROM `users`") ."')") ?>>
```

But it doesn't work.. The button will be blank.. I connected the database just after the body tag by the way..

So how would I read the teamname, color1 color 2 league etc. ?
And also, how would I use the color atributte? like this?

```
<font color=<?php mysql_query("SELECT `color1` FROM `teams` WHERE `team` = '". mysql_query("SELECT `team` FROM `users`") ."')") ?> >
```

And if you don't mind, how would I make that button a text and not a button because I really don't know what tag that contains "value" I should use ..

EDIT: Ok now I made it like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `teamname` FROM `teams` WHERE `team` in (SELECT `team` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$S_SESSION['username']."')");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['teamname'];
```

But it's blank... Please help..

Comment: you need to fetch the dataset from the executed query, there are lots of examples in internet

Comment: You're a long way from building a football manager game. But good luck.

Comment: And your queries are also wrong. what do you want to do

Comment: Get a book, or find a tutorial. Walk before running. (Crawl before walking)

Comment: Well not really a football manager something more simple but thanks.

Comment: Aside from leaving yourself wide open to attack, you should be using mysqli or pdo as mysql has been deprecated.

Comment: `mysql_query` returns resource, not a string so you cannot just print it. Also `SELECT team FROM users` will select whole column 'team' (many rows).

Comment: @the_pete It's deprecated. This may or may not adversely affect its value.

Comment: @Volvox, I added ` "WHERE `username` = '". $_SESSION['username'] ."' ` but it doesn't work. It's blank...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query is wrong :

```
<button value=<?php mysql_query("SELECT `teamname` FROM `teams` WHERE `team` = '". mysql_query("SELECT `team` FROM `users`") ."')") ?>>
```

should be replaced with something like :

```
<button value='<?php 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `teamname` FROM `teams` WHERE `team` in (SELECT distinct `team` FROM `users`)");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $row['teamname'];
?>' ></button>
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer actually helped me. But now what happens is it shows the first  team in the table, not the actual team.. hmm?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ECHO to print the name on the Button also you have to use some conditions to get the unique value from the database. your current query returns multiple values In such case use loop and put your code inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

execute this query first

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT `team` FROM `users`")
```

then put $test in the main query

>